# ListBox SelectedIndex is always -1

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selectedindex

I have a Listbox with Button and Textblock as ItemTemplate. Button has an `onClick` event.

All i want is to get the index of the clicked item, but `SelectedIndex` property in my ListBox is always -1!

How can I get the index of the clicked item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Button control is swallowing the mouse events to provide the Click behavior, so the ListBox never receives any events to tell it that the selection has changed.

As @Alexander suggests, you could use an MVVM-style approach with commands to handle the action in a view model and pass the data context as the parameter.

Alternatively, you could replace the Button with any other layout control and either use the gesture service from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) or use the regular `MouseLeftButtonUp` event. In either instance, the mouse events will bubble up and enable the ListBox to handle selection.

Comment: thank yu very match! Im just remove Button, and create SelectionChanged event with same code) Im a new in C# and devepolment, so its esiest way for me)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to actually select something in your listbox then :p

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data object associated with current ListItem use RouteCommand. Here is example

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Button Margin="5,0" Command="{StaticResource ButtonCommand}" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}">
  </DataTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

You need also define Command at least in ListView.Resources

```
<RoutedCommand x:Key="ButtonCommand"/>
```

And then setup CommandBinding like this

```
<ListView.CommandBindings>
  <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource ButtonCommand}" Executed="Button_Click"/>
</ListView.CommandBindings>
```

In the end write handler

```
    Button_Click(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameter// object that you Specified in CommandParameter
    }
```

In advance you can use any MVVM framework, define all command and commands logic in model and then just bind this commands to corresponding elements.